# Primefaces: Form fields not synced with Managed Bean automatically

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Have a nice day. I don't know if i'm wrong about this. I have a form in my xhtml like this:

```
    <p:outputLabel value="Número de pasajeros" />:
    <p:inputText value="#{vueloMB.instancia.numPasajeros}" maxlength="3" >
    </p:inputText>
    <br />
    <p:outputLabel value="Hora de salida" />:
    <p:calendar value="#{vueloMB.instancia.fechaHoraSalida}" navigator="true"
    mode="popup" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" />
    <br />

    <p:outputLabel value="Avión" />:
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{vueloMB.instancia.avion}" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{vueloMB.aviones}" var="avi"
            itemLabel="#{avi.modelo}" itemValue="#{avi}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <br />
    <p:outputLabel value="Pais de salida" />:
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{vueloMB.instancia.paisSalida}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{vueloMB.paises}" var="pai"
            itemLabel="#{pai.nombre}" itemValue="#{pai}" />
        <f:param name="tipoPais" value="S"></f:param>
        <p:ajax update="ciusal" listener="#{vueloMB.cargarListaCiudades}" process="@this" >
        </p:ajax>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <br />
    <p:outputLabel value="Ciudad de salida" />:
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{vueloMB.instancia.ciudadSalida}"  converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
        id="ciusal" disabled="#{vueloMB.instancia.paisSalida==null}" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{vueloMB.ciudadesSalida}" var="ciu"
            itemLabel="#{ciu.nombre}" itemValue="#{ciu}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <br />
    <p:commandButton value="Guardar" rendered="#{vueloMB.instancia.id == null}" action="#{vueloMB.guardar()}" process="@form" ajax="true" />
</h:form>
```

The dropdown labeled "Ciudad de salida" refreshes another dropdown after i choose a country here, updates the list that feeds the second dropdown and it works fine. The problem is when i press the "Guardar" button to save the entity (vueloMB.instancia is my entity) with JPA, because it doesn't do anything.

So, i added the attribute immediate="true" to the button, it calls the ManagedBean method, but when i see the entity, only the field vueloMB.instancia.paisSalida isn't null, even if i fill all the fields. Because of that, i assumed that, because the dropdown calls an MB method because it refresh the second dropdown, it's value is refreshed on the MB. Based on that, i modified the first field like this:

```
<p:inputText value="#{vueloMB.instancia.numPasajeros}" maxlength="3" >
    <p:ajax />
</p:inputText>
```

I added the ajax tag to my inputText. After doing that, i press the "Guardar" button and the field that i've modified (Número de pasajeros) now it carries the value on vueloMB.instancia.numPasajeros.

So, if i add  to all my fields, when i press the submit button it will work, it will save the entity without problems and all the fields will travel to the managed bean, but is necessary to do that with every field? There's no automatic way JSF does this? Or i have something wrong with my code?

EDIT: Here is the code of the managed bean. A CDI Managed Bean with @ConversationScoped:

```
package com.saplic.fut.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.Conversation;
import javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import com.saplic.fut.daos.VueloDAO;
import com.saplic.fut.entity.Avion;
import com.saplic.fut.entity.Ciudad;
import com.saplic.fut.entity.Pais;
import com.saplic.fut.entity.Vuelo;

@Named("vueloMB")
@ConversationScoped
public class VueloManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -203436251219946811L;

    @Inject
    private VueloDAO vueloDAO;

    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;

    @PostConstruct
    public void iniciarConversacion() {
        if(conversation.isTransient())
            conversation.begin();
    }

    public void finalizarConversacion() {
        if(!conversation.isTransient())
            conversation.end();
    }

    private Vuelo instancia;
    private List<Vuelo> vuelos;
    private List<Avion> aviones = new ArrayList<Avion>();
    private List<Pais> paises = new ArrayList<Pais>();
    private List<Ciudad> ciudadesSalida = new ArrayList<Ciudad>();
    private List<Ciudad> ciudadesAterrizaje = new ArrayList<Ciudad>();
    private Integer idVuelo;

    public String cargarLista() {
        iniciarConversacion();
        vuelos = vueloDAO.cargarVuelos();
        return "/vuelos/lista";
    }

    public void cargarListaCiudades() {
        String tipoLista = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("tipoPais");
        if(tipoLista.equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
            setCiudadesSalida(vueloDAO.cargarCiudades(getInstancia().getPaisSalida()));
        if(tipoLista.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
            setCiudadesAterrizaje(vueloDAO.cargarCiudades(getInstancia().getPaisAterrizaje()));
    }

    public String cargarDetalle() { 
        Vuelo fltVuelo = new Vuelo();
        fltVuelo.setId(getIdVuelo());
        instancia = vueloDAO.cargarDetalle(fltVuelo);
        if(instancia == null)
            setInstancia(new Vuelo());
        //Cargamos lista de aviones para combo
        setAviones(vueloDAO.cargarAviones());
        setPaises(vueloDAO.cargarPaises());
        return "/vuelos/detalle";
    }

    public String guardar() {
        vueloDAO.guardar(instancia);
        finalizarConversacion();
        return cargarLista();
    }

    public String actualizar() {
        vueloDAO.actualizar(instancia);
        finalizarConversacion();
        return cargarLista();
    }

    public String eliminar() {
        vueloDAO.eliminar(instancia);
        finalizarConversacion();
        return cargarLista();
    }

    public Vuelo getInstancia() {
        return instancia;
    }

    public void setInstancia(Vuelo instancia) {
        this.instancia = instancia;
    }

    public List<Vuelo> getVuelos() {
        return vuelos;
    }

    public void setVuelos(List<Vuelo> vuelos) {
        this.vuelos = vuelos;
    }

    public Integer getIdVuelo() {
        return idVuelo;
    }

    public void setIdVuelo(Integer idVuelo) {
        this.idVuelo = idVuelo;
    }

    public List<Avion> getAviones() {
        return aviones;
    }

    public void setAviones(List<Avion> aviones) {
        this.aviones = aviones;
    }

    public List<Pais> getPaises() {
        return paises;
    }

    public void setPaises(List<Pais> paises) {
        this.paises = paises;
    }

    public List<Ciudad> getCiudadesSalida() {
        return ciudadesSalida;
    }

    public void setCiudadesSalida(List<Ciudad> ciudadesSalida) {
        this.ciudadesSalida = ciudadesSalida;
    }

    public List<Ciudad> getCiudadesAterrizaje() {
        return ciudadesAterrizaje;
    }

    public void setCiudadesAterrizaje(List<Ciudad> ciudadesAterrizaje) {
        this.ciudadesAterrizaje = ciudadesAterrizaje;
    }       
}
```

Regards.

Comment: I don't see any bean code… please read  [ask] and [mcve] and the jsf info tab and act accordingly

Comment: You added bean code, but your code (java and xhtml) is not in an mcve format… tried other scopes as well?

Comment: where the cargarDetalle is called?

Comment: @dognose, i added immediate="true" to submit the form without validating fields, but the fields aren't empty! I fill all the fields before submit the form and even with that, when i press the commandButton the method guardar() isn't called, like some kind of field validation is failing.

Comment: @NassimMOUALEK, cargarDetalle is called as the entry point to my form. I have another xhtml with a dataTable showing the list of entities Vuelo. When i click on a row or when i press the button "New record" it calls cargarDetalle() which tries to get an entity from the database if idVuelo isn't empty. Otherwise, it just initializes instancia = new Vuelo(); and loads the xhtml form. Here i fill all the fields with non-empty values and try to submit the form.

Comment: Did you implement toString(), equals() and hashCode() ?

Comment: Also why do you need ConversationScoped and what is it for ?

Comment: @Ced , i haven't implemented those methods, but i don't think are necessary to implement in order to do this. And, ConversationScoped is a scope between RequestScoped and SessionScoped. It's like a mini-session which starts since you start a conversation, normally at the entrypoint of your flow or CRUD, and it stores data in the managed bean doesn't matter if you interact with different views. It finishes until you finish the conversation.

Comment: @OscarCalderon Hey I took the liberty to answer the question but I'm unsure it's gonna be the solution you need. However I had a similar problem that was resolved like this. Please try it even if you don't think it's gonna resolve it, it's specified in the omnifaces doc that you should do it anyway. Give me feedback if it went well or not :) ty.

Answer (score 0):

Your entities must implements the method `equals()` `hashCode()` and `toString` as specified in the [omnifaces showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter). I can't help you much more than that since I'm not familiar with omnifaces and the ConversationScope. I think it's because the two objects are not at the same place in memory so when you use `equals` the result is false. In the case of omnifaces I read it uses `toString()` to see if two objects are equal so if the method is not reimplemented you will have different results.

In other words you have null values because when the value as string comes back from the form it cannot be converted back to the original object. I'd appreciate if someone could attest this as I'm not 100% positive that's what is happening.